# Add ok button in center for JFace dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have extended the JFcae Dialog class and override a method which gives me its Ok and cancel button at side most as in following image.

[image]

But I want these button in center is their any way to do this without doing it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> public Control createButtonBar(Composite parent)      {
>           }

Override this method.